# Windows Phone 8 Functionality Into Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

If I use visual studio 2012 RC write an application for windows phone 8. I want to know whether I can install and run the same application on windows phone 7?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no back-compatibility.  You could do it the other way round, though, and write a WP7 app that would run on WP8

Comment: ok thanks, can you tell me which mobile phone supports WP8 apps?

Comment: Is it not the case that in many cases, as long as you don't use WP8 specific APIs, while the same executable won't run on both 7 and 8, you could build a WP7 executable from mostly the same code?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Mostly.  It *does* need to be built specifically as a WP7 app to run on 7 though.

Comment: so if i build WP8 apps thats run only and only windows 8 phone...is there any solution for this back-compatibility?

Comment: @pooja the answer is above: code carefully and you can build your app twice, once for WP7 and once for WP8.

Comment: @funkybro - almost, but not quite.  You will need to target WP7 in your project properties.  The catch is that if you build a WP8 app, you can't down-target to WP7 so you'll need 2 projects.  It is theoretically possibly to use linked files so you don't need to copy/paste.  I would not recommend this approach though - fixing a bug in WP8 *might* break the whole app on 7.

Comment: @ZombieSheep hmm, might do i guess, in which case you'd need to conditionally do stuff on one or the other.  Nevertheless if you absolutely must target both 7 and 8 I think it's potentially a pretty elegant solution..

Comment: @funkybro is it possible to target both? if yes than how?

Comment: Yes, as I said above if you build a WP7 app it will run on WP8, albeit there may be a slight (and I do mean *slight*) performance hit on very complex apps.

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** possible to build for WP8 and deploy to both WP7 and WP8.

It **is** possible to build for WP7 and deploy to both WP7 and WP8.

The best solution is to code carefully, and clearly separate out your use of WP8-specific APIs.

You could then have two projects, one for WP7 that you build using WP7 tools, and one for WP8, that you build using WP8 tools.  Linked files in visual studio would be a good way of achieving this.